# Proof by Induction: "In a Zoo there are$\ k$ monkeys and$\ k$ monkey bars ...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, puzzle

I'm struggling hard to prove the following statement/riddle by induction, it is given in the current assignement as a challenge. I really want to understand how to exactly approach such excersises. The riddle is on german so I will try to translate:

> In a Zoo there are$\ k$ monkeys and$\ k$ monkey bars (or climbing
>   poles), where as at the top of each bar/pole there hangs a banana.
>   Between adjacent bars there are a total of $\ n $ cross-connections,
>   in which at a bar there are no two connections that begin at the same
>   height. The monkeys now choose all different bars and start climbing.
>   Everytime a monkey encounters a cross-connection he switches the bar
>   and climps on there. As soon as he reaches the top of the bar, he
>   takes (if available) the banana.
>
> Show that for any valid arrangement of the $\ n $ cross-connections
>   that every ape gets a banana.

I know how to proof by Induction, but more like proving $\ 1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ instead of riddles like the one above.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Hint for the inductive step: look at the lowest bar.

Comment: So like: for $\ n=1$ we have one monkey and one monkey bar. And for n cross-connections he will reach the top?

Comment: No, you fix $k$ (monkeys and climbing poles). Then prove the claim by induction on $n$. The case $n = 0$ is trivial: all monkeys just go up. Now assume the claim is all right for $n$ and look at the case with $n+1$ connections. Now consider the lowest connection... [and here it's your turn again].

Comment: At the beginning, and after every time monkeys interchange bars, find the lowest bar that has yet to be crossed. Let the two monkeys on these poles climb in parallel until both reach either end. Then it is clear that the next action is for both monkeys to swap climbing poles, after which there is still a monkey on every pole. So find the lowest uncrossed bar, and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case is when there is only 1 connenction between say bars $k_1\  and\  k_2$ .The monkeys climbing other poles go straight up and the monkeys at $k_1\  and\  k_2$ switch positions.

Now,assume it is true for n connections.When ${n+1}^{th}$ connection is added look at the connection at lowest height.

First,the monkeys there swap positions , and the rest just move up.
Now , it is reduced to a problem with n connection which is true by induction.